# postgresql include accentuated letters in alphabetical order in search results

Tags: postgresql

I have unaccent installed in my postgresql database (although not sure whether this is relevant for my question).

when I do a simple

```
select * from keywords order by keyword desc;
```

returns all entries starting with `œ`then `é` and `è` etc. I want those entries to be within the words that begin with normal `e` so that command should return highest ranking the words starting with `z`, than `y` and so on.

I tried:

```
select unaccent(*) from keywords order by keyword desc;
```

which isn't good as unaccent is full text search only and unaccents the search term, not the results.

Comment: I don't know if its a typo in your query (and if it works at all), but `select unaccent(*)` is weird. Maybe you have only 1 column? Either way, you should put `unaccent` into the `ORDER BY` clause, like `select * from keywords order by unaccent(keyword) desc`

Answer (score 0):

That is a collation problem. Check the one you are using or just use the one you want:

```
with t (w) as ( values ('œ'),('é'),('è'),('z'),('y'))
select w
from t
order by w collate "pt_BR" desc;
 w 
---
 z
 y
 œ
 è
 é
```

In this case `pt_BR` works as intended.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html